# 2 finger scolling goes crazy in firefox

Tags: firefox, touchpad

In Firefox, the 2-finger-scrolling is buggy. If you release one finger while scrolling, the page scrolls to the position the first finger indicates.

It makes this rather nice function impossible to use.

I know that some already are already aware of this problem. I've found a thread where developers talking about this, but since I am new to Ubuntu (and to Linux in general), I don't know how to process the information from the following page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/365943

How should I use the information from that page? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

What I've got from that page is that the fix has been released, but for ["touchpads that don't support multi-finger or sending correct finger width, the jumpy cursor problem is still there"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/365943/comments/76). It might be your case.

Do not forget you may also install [`gpointing-device-settings`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gpointing-device-settings) (click the link to install) to configure your touchpad settings if the default app does not fit your needs.